# Convergence in product space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, product-space

Let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in the product space $X \times Y$. Prove that $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

How can we use the neighborhood idea to prove this statement? please explain me how to prove this?

Comment: Product space usually means that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and you are working with [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). Since you have tagged your post [tag:functional-analysis], it is possible that you are working with normed spaces and with some particular norm on $X\times Y$...? If this is the case, you should clarify this in your post.

Comment: so would it be the case that if I work with the normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ and define an inner product norm on $X\times Y$, the result still holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assume that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ in $X\times Y$. Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ open sets containing respectively $x$ and $y$. Then $O_1\times O_2$ is an open set of $X\times Y$ containing $(x,y)$. By definition of convergence, we can find an integer $n$ such that $(x_n,y_n)\in O_1\times O_2$ if $n\geq N$. So for such $n$, $x_n\in O_1$ and $y_n\in O_2$.
- Conversely, if $x_n\to x$ in $X$ and $y_n\to y$ in $Y$, let $O$ an open subset of $X\times Y$ containing $(x,y)$. By definition of the product topology, we can find $O_1$ open subset of $X$ and $O_2$ open subset of $Y$ containing respectively $x$ and $y$. As it's a homework question, I leave the end of the proof.

Comment: Thanks Davide,I'll complete the proof.

Comment: to prove the necessary part of this question how can we use the projection maps?

Comment: If pi_x(x_n,y_n) goes to pi_x(x,y) then how can we say that x_n goes to x?similarly for y_n?